# What format is this JSON

Tags: json

I have some JSON I have to work with so I am educating myself on JSON parsing etc. Below is an example payload that will be returned from a webservice (I have snipped it to help readability). A pre-cursor to me being able to parse it is me knowing exactly what I am dealing with here... an object, an array, nested arrays, something else?

I've done some simple googling but the samples used are very basic JSON strings.
What do I have here and how can I recognise it for future work?

```
 [
   {
      "RecordProcessID": 251037,
      "CallProcessID": 406,
      "FieldList": [
         {
            "fieldName": "DateofCall",
            "fieldValue": "1/02/2017"
         },
         {
            "fieldName": "TimeOfCall",
            "fieldValue": "17:14:54"
         },
         {
            "fieldName": "Group",
            "fieldValue": "Control"
         },
         {
            "fieldName": "OperatorName",
            "fieldValue": "Jamie"
         },
         {
            "fieldName": "Reference",
            "fieldValue": "251037"
         },
         {
            "fieldName": "RequestType",
            "fieldValue": "(Secured)"
         },
         {
            "fieldName": "23773",
            "fieldValue": "Blue"
         },
         {
            "fieldName": "23774",
            "fieldValue": "9809"
         },
         {
            "fieldName": "FirstName",
            "fieldValue": "Claire"
         },
         {
            "fieldName": "Surname",
            "fieldValue": "Smith"
         },
         {
            "fieldName": "CallersAddress",
            "fieldValue": "some address,"
         },
         {
            "fieldName": "37527",
            "fieldValue": "Yes I have done this"
         },
         {
            "fieldName": "CallersPhone",
            "fieldValue": "00000"
         },
         {
            "fieldName": "CallersMobile",
            "fieldValue": ""
         },
         {
            "fieldName": "Problemaddress",
            "fieldValue": "another address"
         },
         {
            "fieldName": "39081",
            "fieldValue": ""
         },
         {
            "fieldName": "CallDetails",
            "fieldValue": "Secured."
         },
         {
            "fieldName": "PagedTime",
            "fieldValue": "1718"
         },
         {
            "fieldName": "ReturnCallTime",
            "fieldValue": "1721"
         },
         {
            "fieldName": "JobAcceptedBy",
            "fieldValue": "Fred"
         },
         {
            "fieldName": "ProposedActions",
            "fieldValue": "Will go have a look"
         }
      ]
   }
]

,....
```

lots more of the above but snipped here for brevity]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best bet when trying to read JSON is to put it through a linter such as http://json.parser.online.fr/

This gives 
[image: json lint]

So you can see it is an array of hash elements with the keys

- RecordProcessID
- CallProcessID
- FieldList (an array of hashes with the keys)

  - fieldName
  - fieldValue

Not sure what language you are working in, but in ruby to loop through and print the values I could use

```ruby
array = yourjsonsnippit
array.each do |element| # Loop through array
  element.each do |key, value| # Loop through hash elements (RecordProcessID, CallProcessID, FieldList)
    if key == :FieldList # If its an FieldList, loop through its subelements and print them
      value.each do |subelement|
        puts subelement[:fieldName]
        puts subelement[:fieldValue]
      end
    else # print the value
      puts value
    end
  end
end
```

Or to just access a single value for the first element of each array

```
array[0][:FieldList][0][:fieldName]
```

Comment: That is great thanks, now I have something to work/learn with. Not quite sure how I can access "parts" of the entire string when they all have "fieldname" and "fieldValue" before them - for example If I wanted to access the value of RequestType how would I traverse the JSON to get to it... like you would with the DOM?

Comment: Added a few examples of how I could access the elements in ruby. You should just be able to treat it as Arrays and Hashes in your chosen language

Comment: Great thanks. C#. I'm currently loading the remote call into a stringbuilder. I'll check out how to do this with an array

Comment: Any ideas why this question got down voted? Did I violate policy or something? I thanked those who got me where I needed to be and posted the final solution that others may find later. This is affecting my ability to ask more questions so I need to know what constituted a down vote - thanks